# Struts Tags and Expression Language

Tags: java, struts2, expression, jsp-tags

I am having a problem using expression language and struts tags together in a struts2 project. The following code snippet from a jsp file illustrates my problem. The fruits object is passed by a servlet. I know that the error is not from the servlet because when I comment out the form code, it correctly prints out each fruit.

```
<c:forEach var="fruit" items="${fruits}">
    <c:out value="${fruit}"/>
    <s:form>
        <s:checkbox label="${fruit}"></s:checkbox>
    </s:form>
</c:forEach>
```

This doesn't work, and the following error is returned: "According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute label does not accept any expressions".

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to do this in a similar elegant fashion that doesn't require expression language? I really want to use the struts tags for my jsp page. I've also tried with %{fruit} with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading the docs for the Struts tags more carefully.

Your code is failing because the s:checkbox label doesn't accept expressions. It should be just a plain label something like the following

```
<s:checkbox label="Male" name="male" value="true" />
<s:checkbox label="Female" name="male" />
```

For your example above the s:checkboxlist may work better. See http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/checkboxlist.html for more information.